# Import StarUML XMI to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, uml, owl

Good day, colleagues!

I want to convert UML file generated in StarUML to OWL. I'm trying to use Eclipse ODM implementation for this purpose. The problem is I can't import UML file to Eclipse to begin transformation. I create new EMF project and trying to import XMI file from StarUML and get error:

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'null' not found. (file:/C:/Users/Senya/Desktop/test_test_test.xmi, 3, 13)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectByType(XMLHandler.java:1307)
```

Does anybody know how correctly import StarUML files to Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible to export your UML 1.4 model into XMI from StarUML then you could import your model into [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com).

Enterprise Architect has [very good integration with Eclipse](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/mdg/int/eclipse/index.html), having said that I am sure there are other tools out there that could use for a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible because StartUML is UML 1.4 structure while Eclipse is using UML 2.0. You can not convert UML 1.* to UML 2.* because this is not backward compatible !!

Comment: So, there are absolutely no way to convert StarUML UML to UML 2.* ?

Comment: Big changes has been made in the UML 2 specification therefore except very simple diagrams let's say it is impossible.